# If $G/Z(G)$ is abelian then $G$ is abelian?

Tags: abstract-algebra, abelian-groups

> If $G/Z(G)$ is abelian then $G$ is abelian. Give a counter example if this is not true.

I know that if $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic then $G$ is abelian. And $G/Z(G)$ cyclic implies that $G/Z(G)$ is abelian but I don't know how to do with $G/Z(G)$ only abelian.

Comment: Hint: If you've already studied $p$-groups, then you'll know that they have nontrivial center and aren't always abelian.  That could be a good place to start.

Comment: @MatthewKvalheim "What is Z(G)?" A quite standard notation.

Answer (score 10):

Consider the dihedral group of order $8$. It's center is of order $2$. Therefore the quotient with center will be of order $4$ hence abelian but $D_8$ isn't.

Answer (score 7):

Hint: Consider the quaternion group of 8 elements, $\{ \pm 1 , \pm i, \pm j, \pm k\}$.  This group is non abelian.   The center of the group is a group of order 2.

Comment: Ah that's right!  I didn't know what I was thinking.